# REDCap getData Sorting

Tags: php, redcap

I am trying to get the last record using the `REDCap::getData` function and then I apply a `ksort` and `end` function to actually get the last record from a specific project which works fine.

```php
$prefixedRecords = REDCap::getData(
                        'array',    // * PARAM: return_format 
                        null,       // * PARAM: records
                        $pkField,   // * PARAM: fields
                        null,       // * PARAM: events
                        null,       // * PARAM: groups
                        false,      // * PARAM: combine_checkbox_values
                        false,      // * PARAM: exportDataAccessGroups
                        false,      // * PARAM: exportSurveyFields
                        "starts_with([$pkField], '$this->prefix')" // * filterLogic
                );

ksort($prefixedRecords);
end($prefixedRecords);
```

Though I would like to exclude the explicit sorting if there was a way to just get the max record id by using the `REDCap::getData`

As I was debugging the code I also found an optional parameter `sortArray` but this doesn't seems to work as expected as in the debugger I don't really see the array returned in the sorted order as defined.

My intention is to get the MAX Record_ID and then increment it to add a new record into the REDCap , I also tried `array_key_last` though this doesn't guarantee the max as this just picks the last record returned by the `REDCap::getData` function.

Debug Trial suggested by @Stefan Iordache

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `REDCap::reserveNewRecordId()` developer method.

From the REDCap Control Center developer documentation page:

Example #1: Reserving a new record via record auto-numbering

```
$reservedRecordId = REDCap::reserveNewRecordId($project_id);
$data = [['record_id'=>$reservedRecordId]];
$results = REDCap::saveData($project_id, 'json', json_encode($data));
```